# What happens with sidekiq current processes and capistrano

Tags: capistrano, sidekiq

When doing a deployment, are the running sidekiq processes affected, stopped or killed when doing a deployment with capistrano?

Answer (score 7):

Putting `require 'sidekiq/capistrano` in your deploy.rb will add [these default tasks](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/capistrano.rb) on deploy.

If you are doing something that is not purely vanilla, eg. using monit, then you may want to not add the `require 'sidekiq/capistrano` statement and write your own tasks and hooks.

eg.

```
Capistrano::Configuration.instance(:must_exist).load do
  before "deploy:update_code", "sidekiq:quiet"
  after "deploy:stop",    "sidekiq:stop"
  after "deploy:start",   "sidekiq:start"
  before "deploy:restart", "sidekiq:restart"

  namespace :sidekiq do    
    desc "Quiet sidekiq (stop accepting new work)"
    task :quiet, :roles => :app, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue do
      run "/usr/sbin/service sidekiq quiet"
    end

    desc "Stop sidekiq"
    task :stop, :roles => :app, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue do
      run "sudo /usr/bin/monit stop sidekiq"
    end

    desc "Start sidekiq"
    task :start, :roles => :app, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue do
      run "sudo /usr/bin/monit start sidekiq"
    end

    desc "Restart sidekiq"
    task :restart, :roles => :app, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue do
      run "sudo /usr/bin/monit restart sidekiq"
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: Hi @cmaitchison, I was asking more to know what happens with processes running when sidekiq is set to "quiet" and "restart" mode since we have long run processes I want to know if existing processes survive our deployments.

Comment: Sending a "quiet" signal to sidekiq causes it to stop taking jobs from the queue. Jobs in progress are completed as normal. "restart" stops the sidekiq process and starts it again, causing it to pick up the latest version of the deployed code. If you look at the source code link in my answer you can see a "sidekiq_timeout" variable. This is how long it gives jobs to finish on "stop". Make sure this is longer than your longest running job.

Comment: You're right let me take a look and see how I can use this in order to avoid broken processes when deploying thanks!